# Python: Tweepy get location from each tweet

Tags: python, api, twitter, geolocation, tweepy

i'm currently learning Python, and to be more funny i used the Twitter Python's     framework Tweepy. 
I search to get the geolocation from each tweet of someone.
i'm searching to get longitude and latitude , not the name of the town or the country, ex : xx.xxxxx,-yy.yyyyy .

i'm using this part of code :

```
user = api.get_user(sys.argv[2])
        statuses = api.user_timeline(id=user.id, count=nbt)
        for status in statuses:
            print "\n***\n"
            print "Coordinates: " + str(status.coordinates)
```

When i executed my script he just display "Coordinates: None".

---

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some tips !

0wly,

Comment: It's entirely possible that the tweet doesn't have co-ordinate info - very few tweets do. Is this a tweet you know has geolocation data attached to it?

Comment: I was thinking that even if exact geolocation was disabled, i was able to retrieve geolocation from the cities whrere he tweets ^^'. Thank you for you're answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of tweets do not contain geolocation information, and thus no coordinates, which is exactly what you get displayed.

Try your code on a user that systematically geolocalizes its tweets, and it should work.